# why is my program ignoring my if else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

My program should output ‘What is your name?’ only if “hi” and “hello” are typed, but it still outputs ‘What is your name?’ even if I type a number or a single character… I’m so frustrated. Can someone help me out with this? I think it has something to do with the `!phrase.equals` statement…

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prog2 {


public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {



    String phrase;
    String name;
    char Letter;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type a phrase: ");

    phrase = keyboard.nextLine();

    if(!phrase.equals("hi") || !phrase.equals("hello")){   
    System.out.print("What is your name?");               

    Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    name = keyboard1.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Your name is" +name);
    }else{

        Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a Letter: ");

        Letter = (char) System.in.read();
        System.in.read();

        System.out.print("Your letter is "+ Letter);
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't know java, but I think `!phrase.equals("hi")` means phrase is **not** "hi". Try `phrase.equals("hi")` instead.

Comment: why are you always creating a new scanner? You can re-use it!

Comment: omg why didn't I think of that.. silly mistake whoopsie. it works, thanks guys.. i'll look up one the re-usable scanner thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3):

You condition `!phrase.equals("hi") || !phrase.equals("hello")` is always true.

If the word is `hi`, it's `false or true`; if the word is `hello`, it's `true or false`. Otherwise its `true or true`. You did not describe the intended behaviour, thus I can't tell what is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing what you wanted to do. Check [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) laws.

You probably want to do:

`if(!(phrase.equals("hi") || phrase.equals("hello")))`

Which is **not** like what you did because `if(!a || !b)` is not like `if(!(a || b))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if(phrase.equals("hi") || phrase.equals("hello")) {
//rest of your code
}
```